# Javascript exception handling in switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a question regarding exception handling in switch. Is there a way to put some kind of exception handler only for one case? I have multiple cases which represent menu items, but in case of the first one, if the data is not valid it will throw an exception with error details, but I want to add an alert for the user that invalid data was entered. If I will use Try, catch, I need to include entire switch.
Thank you!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s15jnop4/ why exactly are you saying a try catch block cannot be within a switch?

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'A': {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (e) {
    // ...
  }

  break;
}
```

This should work

Comment: Oh, thank you! I'm pretty new to Javascript and didn't know, that I can put Try..catch inside case.